# Why does bluetooth "hci_inquiry" function always returns num_res = 1?

Tags: bluetooth

According to bluetooth specification "hci_inquiry" function - loosely quoted here 
" sends inquiry from local Bluetooth device to nearby remote ( not local)  bluetooth devices and records some data - such as bluetooth device address - upon responses "

It is my understanding that "hci-inquiry" is NOT "pairing" function.

```
        num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, &ii, flags);
```

I have identified / verified three such devices (lsusb) on remote system  , however , "hci_inquiry"  ALWAYS returns "num_rsp = 1".